# Finding original 2d sorted array indexes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've got this array

```
Array    Index
[3,5]  - 0
[1,7]  - 1
[12,4] - 2
[3,2]  - 3
```

And I'm using this sort

```
Arrays.sort(array, (Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) -> {
        Integer numberOfKeys1 = int1[1];
        Integer numberOfKeys2 = int2[1];
        return numberOfKeys1.compareTo(numberOfKeys2);
});
```

To get

```
Array    Index    Index I want 
[3,2]  - 0      - 3
[12,4] - 1      - 2
[3,5]  - 2      - 0
[1,7]  - 3      - 1
```

So my question is. *How can I get original indexes of sorted 2d array?*

Comment: once you sort everything, I don't think it's possible to get the original indices back... if you want to use the original indices frequently in your program, I would suggest keeping two copies of the same array and sorting only one... say what are you trying to do? do you need the original indices frequently or just once?

Comment: @vicky96 I need them frequently, check my answer bellow. If you know a better way to do this, feel free to share.

Comment: that's the most simple and efficient way... you did it

Answer (score 1):

Added 3rd row with indexes

```
array[i][2] = i;
```

and then ran the sort.
Solved, working.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class containing an array and the original index.

```
class ArrayIndex {

    Integer[] data;
    int originalIndex;
}
```

and then sort an `ArrayIndex[] array` like this :

```
Arrays.sort(array, (ArrayIndex a, ArrayIndex b) -> 
        Integer.compare(a.data[1], b.data[1])
);
```

Note above how the `Integer.compare` method simplifies the comparison and avoids boxing.